# Failed to send: "proto.005-PsBabyM1.contract.previously_revealed_key" error

Tags: transactions, error

I was trying to send xtz to Binance. At first, I tried to send from Tezbox, it says the transaction was successful. However my xtz are not deposited yet (after hours). I checked the transaction history, there is no such sending transaction. Then I tried again to send from Galleon, it prompts `proto.005-PsBabyM1.contract.previously_revealed_key` error. It seems my xtz are stuck in the wallet, can any guru help?

Comment: Do you have the transaction hash ? You can search for it in https://tzkt.io/ and the raw json should reveal if there was an error. You can also find it in the mempool in case it is in there

Comment: Thanks @Ezy. Searched in tzkt.io, no sending transaction has been recorded. Please advise how to find in the mempool. I'll attach my transaction history for your reference.

Comment: Screenshot attached. Is the proto.005-PsBabyM1.contract.previously_revealed_key error related to the "Reveal public key" transaction?

Comment: Pls give a direct link or copy your address or the hash of the tx in the body as it is inconvenient to copy by hand from the pic

Comment: Can someone please help me out? I cannot send my tezos coins, I don't want my xtz stuck in the wallet forever. Is there an official Tezos support?

Comment: Are you trying to send the entire balance?

Comment: It turned out that my Galleon version is too old, issue solved after upgraded to latest version, thanks everyone for your help!